# unable to set array values in two php foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays

I have defined two arrays as

```
$array1 = (8,10);
```

Array2 was array of stdobjects which was later converted into below using json decode, encode. Php echo output of the same is below:

```
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
        )

)
```

Later I created one array

```
foreach( $array2 as $value ) 
            {
                $valuesArray[] = array('',$value['id'],Input::get('date'),'0');   
            }
```

What I am trying to do is compare array1 with valuesarray. If $value['id'] i.e. second element matches with any of the element in array1, I will save 4th element of $nnn as 1. If it doesnt match with any of the element, I will save it as 0.
My code below:

```
foreach ($valuesArray as $value2) 
        {
                    foreach ($array1 as $value1)
                    { 
                        if ($value2[1] == $value1) 
                            {$x = 1;} 
                        else 
                            {$x = 0;}
                    }
                $nnn[] = "('','".$value2[1]."','".Input::get('date')."','".$x."')";
                }   

            echo '<pre>',print_r($nnn,1),'</pre>';
```

The output that I am getting is:
Array

```
(
    [0] => ('','6','2016-04-25','0')
    [1] => ('','8','2016-04-25','0')
    [2] => ('','10','2016-04-25','1')
)
```

Correct output should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ('','6','2016-04-25','1')
    [1] => ('','8','2016-04-25','1')
    [2] => ('','10','2016-04-25','0')
)
```

Comment: If you found the value in the first array you need to `break;` your innerForeach loop in the if part, otherwise you will still loop through all values of the first array and check if the next value is still equal to the second array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$nnn = array();
foreach ($valuesArray as $value) {
    $x = (in_array($value[1], $array1))?1:0;
    $nnn[] = "('','".$value[1]."','".Input::get('date')."','{$x}')";
}
```

Comment: Why should OP "try this"?

Comment: because the code loops through valuesArray and compares the values against $array1.